# chart.js - Disable labels

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/). How can I disable the labels, both X and Y?

```
<canvas id="canvas-2010" width="800" style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;"></canvas>
<script>
options = {
    scaleShowLabels : false
}

var lineChartData = {
labels :    ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Maj","Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
datasets : [{
    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    data : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-6147.20,22333.57]
}]                  
}

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas-2010").getContext("2d"), options).Line(lineChartData);
</script>
```

The `scaleShowLabels` option does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `, options` part after the `lineChartData` part, for the last line of the code to be:

```
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas-2010").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option for disable  the labels

```
<canvas id="canvas-2010" width="800" style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;"></canvas>
<script>
options = {
    scaleShowLabels : false
}

var lineChartData = {
labels :    ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Maj","Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
datasets : [{
    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
     ***showScale: false ,***
    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
    data : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-6147.20,22333.57]
}]                  
}

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas-2010").getContext("2d"), options).Line(lineChartData);
</script>
```

I hope it will work